# Drawing shapely object in opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, shapely

I have a shapely polygon like this:

```
polygon = Polygon([(0, 0), (1, 1), (1, 0), (0,0)])
```

When I directly print this polygon in a jupyter notebook cell, it shows the polygon perfectly. On the other side, what I want to do is draw this polygon in an image. How can I do that?

In brief; How can I draw a shapely polygon object on opencv cv2 to process it in a object counting project.opencv

Comment: Use `cv2.drawContours` function

Comment: when I do it, it doesn't put the shapely object to the image, it only puts the edges. I want to use polygon.contains() method on the video frames

Comment: If you want to fill the object pass -1 as the last parameter `cv2.drawContours(img, [points], -1, (0, 255, 255), -1)`